# Did Batman ever get in trouble for computer hacking?

Tags: dc, batman

In *Batman: The Animated Series*, Batman uses his computer to break into the other systems (Police, Other Companies, etc).

In any continuity/universe, did Batman get into trouble for computer hacking?

Comment: No, because he's Batman!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in the *Batman Arkham Origins* video game when you have to break into the police station you hack a computer with Barb’s help.

Batman fights the entire police force before he gets out and nearly gets arrested.

Here’s a picture of him creeping behind a cop in the game.

[image: Batman creeping behind a cop]

Comment: Brandon is the main cop who hates batman in the level

Comment: I'm having deja vu, I swear I have seen this exact answer and screenshot before.